# Certain parameters in dconf keyfiles not being taken into account/used

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome3, dconf

I am working with gnome 3.28.2 on CentOS 7.6 and have been trying to set global values for certain parameters in the dconf key files as explained [here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/3.28/dconf-custom-defaults.html.en) and using the screensaver example [here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-lockscreen.html.en) along with locking the settings explained [here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/3.28/dconf-lockdown.html.en)

I have created a file /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-configuration_gnome with the following contents

```
# These work
[org/gnome/desktop/lockdown]
disable-user-switching=true
disable-lock-screen=true

[org/gnome/desktop/screensaver]
user-switch-enabled=false
lock-enabled=false
lock-delay=uint32 0

[org/gnome/desktop/session]
idle-delay=uint32 0

# These do not work/get taken into account
[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
clock-show-seconds=true

[org/gnome/SessionManager]
logout-prompt=false
```

Certain parameters are taken into account like described in the gnome documentation but others seem to be ignored.  I can change the values via the command line with commands such as
`gsettings set org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt false`
followed by
`dconf update`
but ideally, these values would be set automatically (during installation of the OS for example and not ran in a script during login for each individual account).

Any ideas as to what my problem is? And I would like the logout-prompt=false value to be applied to the gdm user as well. From what I understand it is the account used at the regular login screen but I am having trouble doing that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the schema definition (found in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.SessionManager.gschema.xml`):

```
<schemalist gettext-domain="gnome-session-3.0">
  <schema id="org.gnome.SessionManager" path="/org/gnome/gnome-session/">
    <key name="auto-save-session" type="b">
      <default>false</default>
      ....
```

You can see that the schema ID is **org.gnome.SessionManager**, but the path is **/org/gnome/gnome-session**.  That's kinda confusing, but it looks like you need to use the path in the `dconf` command and the ID in the `gsettings` command.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt
true
$ dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-session/logout-prompt false
$ gsettings get org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt
false
```

So, you'd want your dconf files to have

```
[org/gnome/gnome-session]
logout-prompt=false
```

Also, if you want to set the dconf settings for GDM, place them in /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/ instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly! and thanks for the explanation as well.